# How to set default JDK for new Maven projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

When I create new Maven project in Eclipse wizard, it uses **J2SE-1.5**.
I would like to set it up to use default execution environment, which is **JavaSE-1.8**.

I know I can set it in *pom* or change in project preferences, but I would like to change the default JRE, not doing that for each new project.

When I create a new Java project (not Maven), it works as expected.

I have proper JDK added under "Installed JREs" and it's even only matched with the latest SE, not the Maven-1.5.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen, Maven 3.5.0 and m2e 1.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your project POM add

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

This will apply to maven build cycle, and eclipse m2e integration plugin will pickup those as well. Just remember to maven refresh project after changing such settings in order for eclipse to apply (usually alt+f5 - Refresh Maven project.

If you have parent-child modular structure, you cant put properties into parent POM. It is also possible to "globally" add properties to all projects on given machine using `settings.xml` file like described here [Injecting POM Properties via Settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html)

Comment: Do I need to specify it for each project?

Comment: @Line Yes but you can try to use `settings.xml` to include them globally for given user. Post edited.

Comment: I would like to know why downvoter decided to downvote without any comment.

Comment: How can you know that downvoter didn't leave a comment? ;)
I wrote in question: "I know I can set it in pom or change in project preferences, but I would like to change the default JRE, not doing that for each new project.". There already are the answers on SO which set this for one project - I personally prefer just changing it in project properties. But I'm looking for general solution, as I wrote, DEFAULT JRE. Because this 1.5 comes from somewhere, right?

Comment: @Line thanks for the clarification. Yes default is 1.5. You could give a go to settings.xml and profiles, but it will be a local solution only.

Comment: OK. That will be sufficient. But I don't know where is this settings.xml file. And I also don't understand why the default version is so low.

Comment: I have placed related link in my answer https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html Location of settings.xml is described there as well

Comment: sorry, I can't find it. Where settings.xml should be placed? Do you know why Maven doesn't use my default Eclipse JDK? And on what this version depends? I would like to understand it.

Comment: its all in the link [Injecting POM Properties via Settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html) Maven itself has nothing to do with eclipse, thus version of JDK that eclipse is using has nothing to do with JDK maven uses.

Comment: As for "why maven is using 1.5", here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ 1 min of googling.

Comment: Thanks. "Maven itself has nothing to do with eclipse, thus version of JDK that eclipse is using has nothing to do with JDK maven uses." - that's what I didn't know. I create new project within Eclipse, so I thought that Eclipse has some control over it. I was looking at that page, which you link three times, but I don't see there information where should I place this settings.xml.

Comment: Tell me, and be honest on that, did you ever try to type in google term "settings.xml location" ??? (I know you didnt, but that is just a shame) If dont, give it a try [Settings.xml first page on google](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)